# R aggregate data.frame column for 3 days

Tags: r, xts, zoo

In R I frequently aggregate daily data (in a zoo) by month, using something like this:

```
result <- aggregate(x, as.yearmon, "mean", na.rm=TRUE)
```

Is there a way that I can do this by per 3 day basis?

Comment: If you have date-time variable then probably `cut` would be of use. If you provide a reproducible example, we could tell you more

Comment: If `time(x)` is a `"Date"` class vector then be sure zoo is loaded and replace as.`as.yearmon` with  `as.Date(3 * (as.numeric(d) %/% 3)) + 2` or same but without `+ 2` depending on what you want.  Please provide a reproducible example and desired output as discussed in [mcve] to clarify what it is that you want.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, your comment was super helpful and actually helped me solve a similar problem. You really should post it as an answer.